# How I can optimize this two variable constrained function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I have a cost function $f(x,y)=ax^2+bx+cy^2+dy+e$ with a constraint $x+y\leq m$ that must be optimized. I can solve the problem using Lagrange multipliers method when constraint written as $x+y=m$ but how the solution can be extended to the new constraint?

By the way I write the solution for $x+y=m$ as follow:

$$[L]: \max_{x,y,\lambda}  ax^2+bx+cy^2+dy+e+\lambda(m-x-y) $$
$$[x]: ax+b-\lambda^*=0$$
$$[y]: cy+d-\lambda^*=0$$
$$[\lambda]: m-x^*-y^*=0$$
Optimality condition is obtained by eliminating $\lambda$ from $[x]$ and $[y]$:
$$ax+b=cy+d \to x=\frac{cy+d-b}{a} $$
Now we have two unknown and two equations which results in:
$$x=\frac{cm+b-d}{c+a}$$
$$y=\frac{am+b-d}{c+a}$$

Comment: Hint: There are two cases: either the extreme value is found on the border line $x+y=m$ or in the interior of the half-plane $x+y<m$ (draw an image!). In the latter case, we have $\frac d{dx} f(x^*,y^*) = \frac d{dy} f(x^*,y^*) = 0$.